# OS X clang C++11 and libstdc++ boost compilation problems

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, libstdc++, libc++

I've compiled two Boost library versions - 1.54 and 1.58 similarly:

```
$ mkdir build && ./bootstrap --prefix=$(pwd)/build
$ ./b2 cxxflags="-stdlib=libstdc++" linkflags="-stdlib=libstdc++" && ./b2 install
```

Now, I'm trying to compile this little application:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>

boost::asio::io_service io_service_;
boost::asio::steady_timer timer_(io_service_);

int
main ()
{
  return 0;
}
```

like this:
    $ g++ -c -std=gnu++11 -stdlib=libstdc++ -I main.cpp

It compiles flawlessly for Boost 1.54.0 and gives errors (more than 20) for Boost 1.58.0:

```
boost_1_58_0/build/include/boost/asio/detail/addressof.hpp:31:12: error: no member named 'addressof' in namespace 'std'
using std::addressof;
boost_1_58_0/build/include/boost/asio/detail/handler_alloc_helpers.hpp:37:56: error: no member named 'addressof' in namespace 'boost::asio::detail'
  return asio_handler_allocate(s, boost::asio::detail::addressof(h));
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
boost_1_58_0/build/include/boost/asio/detail/handler_alloc_helpers.hpp:48:54: error: no member named 'addressof' in namespace 'boost::asio::detail'
  asio_handler_deallocate(p, s, boost::asio::detail::addressof(h));
...
```

I guess, this is OS X specific and has something to do with `-std` and `-stdlib` flags I pass, as it compiles if I provide one of these but not both of them simultaneously. I've read a lot about `libc++` and `libstdc++`, but I need these flags as my real code (one may have guessed this was just a demo code) needs these flags in order to be compiled, e.g. I have to use libstdc++ instead of libc++ and I need C++11.

Are there any suggestions on how to use latest boost libraries without giving up these compiler flags?

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile with `-DBOOST_NO_CXX11_ADDRESSOF`.

Also maybe you can compile your code (not boost) using `-stdlib=libc++ -lstdc++` flags (programs on OS X are allowed to use both simultaneously).

Answer (score 0):

```
// Standard library support for addressof.
#if !defined(BOOST_ASIO_HAS_STD_ADDRESSOF)
# if !defined(BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_STD_ADDRESSOF)
#  if defined(__clang__)
#   if defined(BOOST_ASIO_HAS_CLANG_LIBCXX)
#    define BOOST_ASIO_HAS_STD_ADDRESSOF 1
#   elif (__cplusplus >= 201103)
#    define BOOST_ASIO_HAS_STD_ADDRESSOF 1
#   endif // (__cplusplus >= 201103)
#  endif // defined(__clang__)
...
```

It looks like the check for `std::addressof` in boost 1.58 and up is wrong when using clang with libstdc++ and c++11.  If your libstdc++ is too old, then boost will try to use `std::addressof` even though libstdc++ doesn't implement it.  It looks like you can define `BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_STD_ADDRESSOF` to work around that problem.

Comment: The libstdc++ that Apple ships on Mac OS X is quite old. (4.2.1, IIRC).